# Device Fonts settings are affecting app fonts - Ionic 6 (Capacitor) Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

Our team is struggling with an issue in Ionic 6.

We would like our mobile app fonts to be independent of device fonts settings on Android phone. We would like, device fonts settings should not affect our app font size etc.

There is a plugin available for Ionic 3 (Cordova) But for Capacitor, we haven't found a solution.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same (Cordova) plugin in Capacitor.

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/cordova/using-cordova-plugins

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins/cordova

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you can use Cordova plugins in Capacitor too.

That being said, fixing the value of the `textZoom` property of your webView to 100(%) is all you need to achieve what you're after. You can do this, for example, in the `onStart` method of your `MainActivity.kt/java`.

```
override fun onStart() {
  ...
  bridge.webView.settings.textZoom = 100
}
```